# Windows Server 2003 x64 Rebooting - PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA (50)

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server-2005

Windows Server 2003 x64 R2 Standard Edition it's rebooting by itself. I originally thought it wast Paragon Hard Disk Manager Premium 15. After uninstalled Paragon HDM 15 it stopped rebooting but it did it again. This box it's a production box running SQL Server 2005.

Here is the analysis of the dump file:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.3.9600.17298 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Users\candrade\Desktop\Minidump from DBserver\MEMORY.DMP]
Kernel Summary Dump File: Only kernel address space is available


************* Symbol Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
Windows Server 2003 Kernel Version 3790 (Service Pack 2) MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: Server, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Built by: 3790.srv03_sp2_qfe.150311-1502
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff800`01000000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff800`011d9280
Debug session time: Thu Apr  9 16:22:47.268 2015 (UTC - 4:00)
System Uptime: 10 days 15:47:49.563
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
.............................................................
Loading User Symbols
PEB is paged out (Peb.Ldr = 000007ff`fffd6018).  Type ".hh dbgerr001" for details
Loading unloaded module list
..................................................
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 50, {fffffadf1c63fea9, 0, fffffade5ae92290, 0}

Probably caused by : disk.sys ( disk!memcpy+60 )

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

3: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA (50)
Invalid system memory was referenced.  This cannot be protected by try-except,
it must be protected by a Probe.  Typically the address is just plain bad or it
is pointing at freed memory.
Arguments:
Arg1: fffffadf1c63fea9, memory referenced.
Arg2: 0000000000000000, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation.
Arg3: fffffade5ae92290, If non-zero, the instruction address which referenced the bad memory
    address.
Arg4: 0000000000000000, (reserved)

Debugging Details:
------------------


READ_ADDRESS:  fffffadf1c63fea9 Nonpaged pool expansion

FAULTING_IP: 
disk!memcpy+60
fffffade`5ae92290 488b040a        mov     rax,qword ptr [rdx+rcx]

MM_INTERNAL_CODE:  0

IMAGE_NAME:  disk.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  45d69708

MODULE_NAME: disk

FAULTING_MODULE: fffffade5ae8e000 disk

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x50

PROCESS_NAME:  wmiprvse.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  1

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17298 (debuggers(dbg).141024-1500) amd64fre

TRAP_FRAME:  fffffade552934c0 -- (.trap 0xfffffade552934c0)
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=fffffade6b6b0540 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=fffffade6de33070
rdx=00000000ae80ce39 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffffade5ae92290 rsp=fffffade55293658 rbp=fffffade700461b0
 r8=0000000000000018  r9=0000000000000003 r10=5bcd845281da000a
r11=fffffade6de33070 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
disk!memcpy+0x60:
fffffade`5ae92290 488b040a        mov     rax,qword ptr [rdx+rcx] ds:fffffadf`1c63fea9=????????????????
Resetting default scope

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff800010a69dd to fffff8000102eb90

STACK_TEXT:  
fffffade`552933e8 fffff800`010a69dd : 00000000`00000050 fffffadf`1c63fea9 00000000`00000000 fffffade`552934c0 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffffade`552933f0 fffff800`0102d759 : 00000000`00000000 fffff800`012844ec 0000fade`5af1e100 fffffade`55293750 : nt!MmAccessFault+0xa1f
fffffade`552934c0 fffffade`5ae92290 : fffffade`5ae8f8dd 0012019f`00000000 fffffade`6c229400 fffffa80`00000000 : nt!KiPageFault+0x119
fffffade`55293658 fffffade`5ae8f8dd : 0012019f`00000000 fffffade`6c229400 fffffa80`00000000 fffffade`70046670 : disk!memcpy+0x60
fffffade`55293660 fffffade`5b665f1d : 00000000`01b3de68 00000000`00000060 fffffade`6cd9a700 fffffade`55293cf0 : disk!DiskDeviceControl+0x7ed
fffffade`552938d0 fffff800`0137ea99 : fffffade`6cd9a700 00000000`00000001 00000000`beaa0251 fffffade`6cd9a700 : PartMgr!PmDeviceControl+0x4d
fffffade`55293960 fffffade`5ae39962 : 00000000`00000000 fffffade`6cd9a700 fffffade`6cd9a700 fffffade`6e0ad4c0 : nt!RawDispatch+0x159
fffffade`552939b0 fffffade`5ae39962 : ffffffff`ffffffff fffffade`6cd9a700 fffffade`6cd9a700 fffffade`6cddd170 : fltMgr!FltpDispatch+0x1c2
fffffade`55293a10 fffff800`01284071 : 00000000`00000000 fffffade`55293cf0 00000000`00000001 fffffade`6ca2a3f0 : fltMgr!FltpDispatch+0x1c2
fffffade`55293a70 fffff800`01283b76 : fffffade`6b7ffec0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!IopXxxControlFile+0xa79
fffffade`55293b90 fffff800`0102e63d : fffffade`55293c18 00000000`00000000 00000000`6f4d8b01 fffffade`6b7ffec0 : nt!NtDeviceIoControlFile+0x56
fffffade`55293c00 00000000`77ef04aa : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x3
00000000`01b3dd58 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x77ef04aa


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
disk!memcpy+60
fffffade`5ae92290 488b040a        mov     rax,qword ptr [rdx+rcx]

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  3

SYMBOL_NAME:  disk!memcpy+60

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x50_disk!memcpy+60

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x50_disk!memcpy+60

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0x50_disk!memcpy+60

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {c61dfbc1-fe5e-35f2-df9e-8ca950717906}

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

---

I have called Dell and they analyzed the the dump file. ENG64.SYS and EX64.SYS point to Symantec EndPoint Protection.

Unloaded modules:
fffffade`52395000 fffffade`523b8000   ENG64.SYS
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  00023000
fffffade`523b8000 fffffade`525c6000   EX64.SYS
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  0020E000

I have uninstalled SEP but the server keep crashing with the same error code. This time shows something different. Using lmnt shows the following (not more ENG64.SYS and EX64.SYS)

```
7: kd> lmnt
```

start             end                 module name
fffff800`00800000 fffff800`0085e000   hal      hal.dll      Wed Aug 13 06:15:40 2008 (48A2B44C)
fffff800`01000000 fffff800`0149d000   nt       ntkrnlmp.exe Wed Mar 11 20:43:04 2015 (5500E118)
fffff97f`ff000000 fffff97f`ff47f000   win32k   win32k.sys   Wed Feb 25 20:37:59 2015 (54EE78F7)
fffff97f`ff47f000 fffff97f`ff4a7000   dxg      dxg.sys      Sat Feb 17 00:43:08 2007 (45D695EC)
fffff97f`ff4a7000 fffff97f`ff511000   ati2dvag ati2dvag.dll Wed Apr 05 23:05:07 2006 (44348563)
fffff97f`ff511000 fffff97f`ff573000   ati2cqag ati2cqag.dll Wed Apr 05 21:58:55 2006 (443475DF)
fffff97f`ff573000 fffff97f`ff5ba000   atikvmag atikvmag.dll Wed Apr 05 22:25:50 2006 (44347C2E)
fffff97f`ff5ba000 fffff97f`ff632000   ATMFD    ATMFD.DLL    Thu Feb 19 21:42:11 2015 (54E69F03)
fffff97f`ff632000 fffff97f`ff660000   RDPDD    RDPDD.dll    Thu Mar 24 23:54:35 2005 (42438B7B)
fffffade`567ee000 fffffade`5682c000   RDPWD    RDPWD.SYS    Tue May 01 08:52:14 2012 (4F9FDC7E)
fffffade`5745c000 fffffade`57529000   srv      srv.sys      Thu Feb 17 11:53:58 2011 (4D5D52A6)
fffffade`575fb000 fffffade`57692000   HTTP     HTTP.sys     Tue Oct 20 12:25:42 2009 (4ADDE486)
fffffade`57bce000 fffffade`57bef000   WudfPf   WudfPf.sys   Mon Jul 13 20:05:37 2009 (4A5BCBD1)
fffffade`57c27000 fffffade`57c2e000   BASFND   BASFND.sys   Thu Apr 24 19:17:12 2003 (3EA87078)
fffffade`587a7000 fffffade`587c8000   Cdfs     Cdfs.SYS     Sat Feb 17 00:59:37 2007 (45D699C9)
fffffade`58823000 fffffade`588f0000   mrxsmb   mrxsmb.sys   Wed Jul 06 10:22:48 2011 (4E146FB8)
fffffade`588f0000 fffffade`58941000   rdbss    rdbss.sys    Wed Feb 24 11:04:53 2010 (4B854E25)
fffffade`58941000 fffffade`589c6b00   UimFIO   UimFIO.SYS   Sat Nov 22 13:41:06 2014 (5470D8C2)
fffffade`58a70000 fffffade`58abd000   afd      afd.sys      Thu May 29 21:36:29 2014 (5387E09D)
fffffade`58abd000 fffffade`58afb000   ipnat    ipnat.sys    Sat Feb 17 00:31:30 2007 (45D69332)
fffffade`58afb000 fffffade`58b55000   netbt    netbt.sys    Sat Feb 17 01:00:23 2007 (45D699F7)
fffffade`58b9b000 fffffade`58c98000   tcpip    tcpip.sys    Mon Sep 15 16:41:08 2014 (54174EE4)
fffffade`58c98000 fffffade`58cae000   msgpc    msgpc.sys    Sat Feb 17 00:31:07 2007 (45D6931B)
fffffade`58cae000 fffffade`58cd9000   ipsec    ipsec.sys    Sat Feb 17 01:01:35 2007 (45D69A3F)
fffffade`58cd9000 fffffade`58ced000   Npfs     Npfs.SYS     Sat Feb 17 00:29:55 2007 (45D692D3)
fffffade`59198000 fffffade`591b8000   usbhub   usbhub.sys   Sat Feb 17 00:52:07 2007 (45D69807)
fffffade`592b8000 fffffade`592cc000   NDProxy  NDProxy.SYS  Wed Nov 27 15:17:43 2013 (52965367)
fffffade`59428000 fffffade`59454000   update   update.sys   Mon May 28 08:21:19 2007 (465AC93F)
fffffade`59454000 fffffade`5946a000   termdd   termdd.sys   Sat Feb 17 00:33:42 2007 (45D693B6)
fffffade`594b0000 fffffade`59507000   rdpdr    rdpdr.sys    Sat Feb 17 00:30:39 2007 (45D692FF)
fffffade`59507000 fffffade`5952a000   raspptp  raspptp.sys  Sat Feb 17 01:01:23 2007 (45D69A33)
fffffade`5952a000 fffffade`5953e000   raspppoe raspppoe.sys Sat Feb 17 00:31:42 2007 (45D6933E)
fffffade`5953e000 fffffade`5956a000   ndiswan  ndiswan.sys  Sat Feb 17 01:01:23 2007 (45D69A33)
fffffade`5956a000 fffffade`59590000   rasl2tp  rasl2tp.sys  Sat Feb 17 01:00:35 2007 (45D69A03)
fffffade`59590000 fffffade`595d9000   ks       ks.sys       Sat Feb 17 01:02:44 2007 (45D69A84)
fffffade`595d9000 fffffade`595ef000   redbook  redbook.sys  Thu Mar 24 20:39:21 2005 (42435DB9)
fffffade`595ef000 fffffade`5960a000   cdrom    cdrom.sys    Thu Mar 24 20:39:39 2005 (42435DCB)
fffffade`5960a000 fffffade`59621000   imapi    imapi.sys    Thu Mar 24 20:40:04 2005 (42435DE4)
fffffade`59621000 fffffade`59644000   serial   serial.sys   Thu Mar 24 20:38:54 2005 (42435D9E)
fffffade`59644000 fffffade`59667000   VIDEOPRT VIDEOPRT.SYS Sat Feb 17 00:50:17 2007 (45D69799)
fffffade`59667000 fffffade`5988d000   ati2mtag ati2mtag.sys Wed Apr 05 23:04:41 2006 (44348549)
fffffade`5988d000 fffffade`598c7000   USBPORT  USBPORT.SYS  Sat Jul 20 15:17:39 2013 (51EAE253)
fffffade`598c7000 fffffade`598e0000   bxnd52a  bxnd52a.sys  Fri Jan 14 17:23:46 2011 (4D30CCF2)
fffffade`5a47c000 fffffade`5a488000   dump_percsas dump_percsas.sys Mon Jan 19 16:40:20 2009 (4974F344)
fffffade`5a48c000 fffffade`5a499000   ptilink  ptilink.sys  Thu Mar 24 20:38:44 2005 (42435D94)
fffffade`5a49c000 fffffade`5a4a7000   raspti   raspti.sys   Thu Mar 24 20:44:11 2005 (42435EDB)
fffffade`5a4ac000 fffffade`5a4ba000   fdc      fdc.sys      Sat Feb 17 00:47:27 2007 (45D696EF)
fffffade`5a4c3000 fffffade`5a4cf000   ndisuio  ndisuio.sys  Sat Feb 17 00:30:57 2007 (45D69311)
fffffade`5a50a000 fffffade`5a513000   watchdog watchdog.sys Thu Mar 24 20:43:05 2005 (42435E99)
fffffade`5a541000 fffffade`5a54b000   mnmdd    mnmdd.SYS    Thu Mar 24 20:42:22 2005 (42435E6E)
fffffade`5a588000 fffffade`5a590080   usbuhci  usbuhci.sys  Sat Jul 20 15:17:38 2013 (51EAE252)
fffffade`5a598000 fffffade`5a5a2000   RDPCDD   RDPCDD.sys   Thu Mar 24 20:38:04 2005 (42435D6C)
fffffade`5a5af000 fffffade`5a5bd000   TDTCP    TDTCP.SYS    Sat Feb 17 00:33:41 2007 (45D693B5)
fffffade`5a5e6000 fffffade`5a5f0280   HIDPARSE HIDPARSE.SYS Tue Jul 02 21:17:47 2013 (51D37BBB)
fffffade`5a5f6000 fffffade`5a603000   mouclass mouclass.sys Thu Mar 24 20:38:09 2005 (42435D71)
fffffade`5a60d000 fffffade`5a617000   rasacd   rasacd.sys   Thu Mar 24 20:44:16 2005 (42435EE0)
fffffade`5a61d000 fffffade`5a627000   Fs_Rec   Fs_Rec.SYS   Thu Mar 24 20:39:42 2005 (42435DCE)
fffffade`5a62d000 fffffade`5a63b000   vga      vga.sys      Thu Mar 24 20:42:24 2005 (42435E70)
fffffade`5a644000 fffffade`5a64e000   ndistapi ndistapi.sys Fri Jul 08 10:19:34 2011 (4E1711F6)
fffffade`5a66b000 fffffade`5a677c80   usbehci  usbehci.sys  Sat Jul 20 15:17:38 2013 (51EAE252)
fffffade`5a72e000 fffffade`5a735000   Beep     Beep.SYS     Thu Mar 24 20:38:06 2005 (42435D6E)
fffffade`5ac5f000 fffffade`5ac93000   Mup      Mup.sys      Tue Apr 12 15:02:21 2011 (4DA4A1BD)
fffffade`5ac93000 fffffade`5acf9000   NDIS     NDIS.sys     Sat Feb 17 01:00:17 2007 (45D699F1)
fffffade`5acf9000 fffffade`5adfe000   Ntfs     Ntfs.sys     Sat Feb 17 01:00:15 2007 (45D699EF)
fffffade`5adfe000 fffffade`5ae32000   KSecDD   KSecDD.sys   Wed Jan 14 02:57:40 2015 (54B62174)
fffffade`5ae32000 fffffade`5ae71000   fltMgr   fltMgr.sys   Sun Jan 06 19:53:45 2013 (50EA1C99)
fffffade`5ae71000 fffffade`5ae8e000   CLASSPNP CLASSPNP.SYS Sat Feb 17 00:59:43 2007 (45D699CF)
fffffade`5ae8e000 fffffade`5aea3000   disk     disk.sys     Sat Feb 17 00:47:52 2007 (45D69708)
fffffade`5aea3000 fffffade`5af06000   storport storport.sys Mon Oct 22 07:16:56 2007 (471C86A8)
fffffade`5af06000 fffffade`5af33000   atapi    atapi.sys    Sat Feb 17 00:47:46 2007 (45D69702)
fffffade`5af33000 fffffade`5afbb000   bxvbda   bxvbda.sys   Thu Jan 06 13:55:14 2011 (4D261012)
fffffade`5afbb000 fffffade`5b006000   volsnap  volsnap.sys  Tue Aug 21 09:12:06 2012 (50338926)
fffffade`5b006000 fffffade`5b04d000   dmio     dmio.sys     Sat Feb 17 00:50:25 2007 (45D697A1)
fffffade`5b04d000 fffffade`5b08d000   ftdisk   ftdisk.sys   Sat Feb 17 00:48:06 2007 (45D69716)
fffffade`5b08d000 fffffade`5b0a3000   MountMgr MountMgr.sys Sat Feb 17 00:46:25 2007 (45D696B1)
fffffade`5b0a3000 fffffade`5b17d000   Wdf01000 Wdf01000.sys Sat Jan 19 01:33:27 2008 (479199B7)
fffffade`5b17d000 fffffade`5b19e000   pci      pci.sys      Sat Feb 17 00:38:11 2007 (45D694C3)
fffffade`5b19e000 fffffade`5b1f2000   ACPI     ACPI.sys     Sat Feb 17 00:37:56 2007 (45D694B4)
fffffade`5b2f3000 fffffade`5b304000   Dfs      Dfs.sys      Sat Feb 17 00:30:58 2007 (45D69312)
fffffade`5b365000 fffffade`5b377000   intelppm intelppm.sys Thu Mar 24 20:39:38 2005 (42435DCA)
fffffade`5b378000 fffffade`5b38a000   wanarp   wanarp.sys   Sat Feb 17 00:31:35 2007 (45D69337)
fffffade`5b38b000 fffffade`5b39d000   netbios  netbios.sys  Sat Feb 17 00:31:02 2007 (45D69316)
fffffade`5b39e000 fffffade`5b3b0000   Fips     Fips.SYS     Sat Feb 17 00:38:28 2007 (45D694D4)
fffffade`5b5fb000 fffffade`5b605000   kdcom    kdcom.dll    Thu Mar 24 23:54:15 2005 (42438B67)
fffffade`5b60b000 fffffade`5b614000   BOOTVID  BOOTVID.dll  Thu Mar 24 23:54:04 2005 (42438B5C)
fffffade`5b61b000 fffffade`5b624000   WMILIB   WMILIB.SYS   Thu Mar 24 20:43:56 2005 (42435ECC)
fffffade`5b62b000 fffffade`5b634000   isapnp   isapnp.sys   Sat Feb 17 00:38:08 2007 (45D694C0)
fffffade`5b63b000 fffffade`5b649000   WDFLDR   WDFLDR.SYS   Sat Jan 19 01:32:33 2008 (47919981)
fffffade`5b64b000 fffffade`5b65b000   PCIIDEX  PCIIDEX.SYS  Sat Feb 17 00:47:39 2007 (45D696FB)
fffffade`5b65b000 fffffade`5b66b000   PartMgr  PartMgr.sys  Sat Feb 17 00:59:56 2007 (45D699DC)
fffffade`5b66b000 fffffade`5b677000   percsas  percsas.sys  Mon Jan 19 16:40:20 2009 (4974F344)
fffffade`5b67b000 fffffade`5b686000   crcdisk  crcdisk.sys  Thu Mar 24 20:42:06 2005 (42435E5E)
fffffade`5b70b000 fffffade`5b717000   serenum  serenum.sys  Thu Mar 24 20:38:50 2005 (42435D9A)
fffffade`5b72b000 fffffade`5b737000   dcdbas64 dcdbas64.sys Thu Jun 11 13:44:04 2009 (4A314264)
fffffade`5b74b000 fffffade`5b75a000   TDI      TDI.SYS      Sat Feb 17 00:33:32 2007 (45D693AC)
fffffade`5b77b000 fffffade`5b787000   dump_diskdump dump_diskdump.sys Mon Oct 22 06:35:03 2007 (471C7CD7)
fffffade`5b78b000 fffffade`5b799000   kbdclass kbdclass.sys Sat Feb 17 00:46:27 2007 (45D696B3)
fffffade`5b7db000 fffffade`5b7e7000   Dxapi    Dxapi.sys    Thu Mar 24 20:39:08 2005 (42435DAC)
fffffade`5b80b000 fffffade`5b816000   secdrv   secdrv.sys   Wed Sep 13 09:18:38 2006 (4508052E)
fffffade`5b81b000 fffffade`5b828000   Msfs     Msfs.SYS     Thu Mar 24 20:40:07 2005 (42435DE7)
fffffade`5b83b000 fffffade`5b848000   mssmbios mssmbios.sys Sat Feb 17 00:38:13 2007 (45D694C5)
fffffade`5b90b000 fffffade`5b913000   audstub  audstub.sys  Thu Mar 24 20:43:08 2005 (42435E9C)
fffffade`5b993000 fffffade`5b99b000   CdaC15BA CdaC15BA.sys Wed Dec 10 10:11:51 2003 (3FD737B7)
fffffade`5b99b000 fffffade`5b9a3000   CdaD10BA CdaD10BA.sys Wed Dec 10 10:11:51 2003 (3FD737B7)
fffffade`5b9c3000 fffffade`5b9cb000   Null     Null.SYS     Thu Mar 24 20:38:07 2005 (42435D6F)
fffffade`5b9fb000 fffffade`5ba02000   pciide   pciide.sys   Thu Mar 24 20:39:26 2005 (42435DBE)
fffffade`5ba02000 fffffade`5ba09000   dmload   dmload.sys   Thu Mar 24 20:42:29 2005 (42435E75)
fffffade`5bc2b000 fffffade`5bc30e80   ksthunk  ksthunk.sys  Sat Feb 17 00:46:33 2007 (45D696B9)
fffffade`5be11000 fffffade`5be12400   swenum   swenum.sys   Sat Feb 17 00:46:35 2007 (45D696BB)
fffffade`5be21000 fffffade`5be22e00   USBD     USBD.SYS     Sat Jul 20 15:17:38 2013 (51EAE252)

Unloaded modules:
fffffade`587c8000 fffffade`587dd000   HIDCLASS.SYS
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  00015000
fffffade`5a67b000 fffffade`5a685000   hidusb.sys
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  0000A000
fffffade`5a5af000 fffffade`5a5ba000   usbccgp.sys
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  0000B000
fffffade`5b71b000 fffffade`5b727000   kbdhid.sys
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  0000C000
fffffade`5a578000 fffffade`5a582000   mouhid.sys
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  0000A000
fffffade`58926000 fffffade`58941000   UimBus.sys
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  0001B000
fffffade`5a6cc000 fffffade`5a6d1000   uim_devim.sys
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  00005000
fffffade`589c7000 fffffade`58a70000   uim_im.sys
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  000A9000
fffffade`5b77b000 fffffade`5b787000   kbdhid.sys
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  0000C000
fffffade`58cf0000 fffffade`58d0d000   i8042prt.SYS
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  0001D000
fffffade`5a531000 fffffade`5a53a000   Sfloppy.SYS
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  00009000
fffffade`5b75b000 fffffade`5b767000   Flpydisk.SYS
    Timestamp: unavailable (00000000)
    Checksum:  00000000
    ImageSize:  0000C000

Comment: That error is very often caused by faulty hardware, mainly memory. Have you ruled out a hardware fault?

Comment: Totally agree with Massimo.  If the kernel is looking for a page in non-paged memory (physical RAM), and it doesn't find it - BANG!  Try swapping out DIMMs.

Comment: Have there been any recent hardware changes? What brand/model of server is it? You may be able to use the vendor-supplied diagnostics tools to narrow down any hardware faults

Comment: Also, are the bug checks consistent in terms of the stop code, etc, or is it fairly random?

Comment: The box is a Dell PowerEdge 2950. No changes on hardware. The same error code every time it reboots and the same results in the Debugger. I will run the diagnostics tools on the Memory and Hard Drive before I call Dell. Thanks All